# Creating flange from 3D surface

Tags: solidworks

I have essentially a hollow tube created from 3D splines that define the inner and outer surfaces.  How can I extrude a flange from the exterior surface?

I did not mention, this is Solidworks 2012.

This can be done by wrapping onto a cylinder, but my thinking is that a 3D extrude would be more appropriate that would extrude from one inner surface to an outer surface ... like a boundary extrude.

[Wrapping onto a cylinder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJCvx.png)

This is a spline surface, and I can't figure out how to do it appropriately.  In my real world example, this is actually a tube, so I can't blind extrude, because it will also fill the inside void.
[image: Spline surface]

Comment: It depends upon the software you are using. In Inventor I would probably make a plane through the center of the tube and revolve the shape of the flange. I have not done 3d in Autocad in a while but would probably do the same thing.

Comment: I dont think the question provides enough insight to answer in one way or another.